# SSRS report for SAP hana db

Tags: reporting-services, odbc, hana

How to create a SSRS REPORT from SAP HANA DB. I have created a system DSN in ODBC driver and got success message while checking the test connection. But while creating a data set in SSRS report, getting error message as **Datasource name not found and no default driver specified**

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to install 32-bit HANA Client (NTintel), setup a new ODBC with 32-bit HANA ODBC driver, and try the connection again in your report project in Visual Studio.